# PHP: How to delete specific SubArray of an Array by multiple values to match?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, key-value

Let's say I have an array like this one:

```
$cart = [
  [ 'productID' => '11111' , 'size' => 'M' , 'quantity' => 2 ],
  [ 'productID' => '11111' , 'size' => 'L' , 'quantity' => 4 ],
  [ 'productID' => '22222' , 'size' => 'S' , 'quantity' => 3 ],
  [ 'productID' => '22222' , 'size' => 'L' , 'quantity' => 7 ],
  [ 'productID' => '33333' , 'size' => 'M' , 'quantity' => 1 ]
];
```

Now I would like to be able to delete from array by multiple values like this:

```
removeElementFromArray( $cart , [ 'productID' => '11111' , 'size' => 'M' ] );
```

But my problem is I do not understand the logic how to achieve this. This is what I have

```
function removeElementFromArray($targetArray=[],$needles=[]){

  foreach( $targetArray as $subKey => $subArray ){

    // This is wrong because $removeIt becomes TRUE by any needle matched
    // but I want it to become TRUE only if all $needles match.
    foreach( $needles as $key => $value ){
      if( $subArray[$key] == $value ){
        $removeIt = TRUE;
      }
    }

    // delete row from array
    if( $removeIt == TRUE ){ unset($targetArray[$subKey]); }

  }

  // return
  return $targetArray;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple modification to your code can work.  This starts off assuming that you can remove an element, then if any of the values don't match, then flag it as not matching (and stop looking)...

```
function removeElementFromArray($targetArray=[],$needles=[]){

    foreach( $targetArray as $subKey => $subArray ){
        $removeIt = true;
        foreach( $needles as $key => $value ){
            if( $subArray[$key] !== $value ){
                $removeIt = false;
                break;
            }
        }

        // delete row from array
        if( $removeIt == TRUE ){ 
            unset($targetArray[$subKey]); 
        }

    }

    // return
    return $targetArray;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ultra short `array_filter` version with `array_diff_assoc`:

```
function removeElementFromArray($targetArray, $needles) {
    return array_filter($targetArray, function ($item) use ($needles) {
        return !empty(array_diff_assoc($needles, $item));
    });
}
```

Fiddle [here](https://3v4l.org/CpE9I).